# How do I make a function in R to check for data errors?

Tags: r, function, data-cleaning

I have a lot of csv files of temperature data which I am importing into R to process. These files look like:

```
ID   Date.Time          temp1    temp2
1    08/13/17 14:48:18  15.581  -0.423
2    08/13/17 16:48:18  17.510  -0.423
3    08/13/17 18:48:18  15.390  -0.423
```

Sometimes the temperature readings in columns 3 and 4 are clearly wrong and have to be replaced with NA values. I know that anything over 50 or under -50 is an error. I'd like to just remove these right away. Using

```
df[,c(3,4)]<- replace(df[,c(3,4)], df[,c(3,4)] >50, NA)
df[,c(3,4)] <- replace(df[,c(3,4)], df[,c(3,4)] < -50, NA)
```

works but I don't really want to have to repeat this for every file because it seems messy.

I would like to make a function to replace all this like:

```
df<-remove.errors(df[,c(3,4)])
```

I've tried:

```
remove.errors<-function (df) {
  df[,]<- replace(df[,], df[,] > 50, NA)
  df[,]<- replace(df[,], df[,] < -50, NA)
  }

df<-remove.errors(df[,c(3,4)])
```

This works but unfortunately only keeps the 3rd and 4th columns and the first two disappear. I've played around with this code for far too long and tried some other things which didn't work at all.

I know I'm probably missing something basic. Anyone have any tips on making a function which will replace values in columns 3 and 4 with NAs without changing the first two columns?

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Try this. It uses only base R.

```
clean <- function(x, max = 50, min = -max) replace(x, x > max | x < min, NA)
df[3:4] <- clean(df[3:4])
```

**1a)** Alternately we could do this (which does not overwrite `df`):

```
transform(df, temp1 = clean(temp1), temp2 = clean(temp2))
```

**2)** Adding in magrittr we could do this:

```
library(magrittr)
df[3:4] %<>% { clean(.) }
```

**3)** In dplyr we could do this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(3:4, clean)
```

Comment: Would it be better to use `lapply(df[3:4], clean)`? It wouldn't go through conversion to a `matrix`.

Comment: If you're going for code readability, absolutely right. With both small and large frames, however, the `lapply` version takes half the time (benchmarked up to 5e5 rows). For me the issue is less about performance and more about seeing habits that will bite unsuspecting programmers at some point (not here), e.g., the use of `apply(MARGIN=1,...)` on a `data.frame` with different column classes.

Comment: Actually `clean(df[3:4])` produces a data.frame, not a matrix.

Comment: Okay, so `class(x > max | x < min)` is `matrix`, which is a different thing. My apologies, not saying your code is bad or doesn't work well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `df` in `remove.errors`; you can also write the `replace` statement more succinctly using `abs`:

```
remove.errors<-function (df) {
    df[]<- replace(df, abs(df) > 50, NA)
    return(df)
}
```

Or a cleaner/safer alternative using `dplyr` that takes care of `numeric`/non-`numeric` columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(replace(., abs(.) > 50, NA)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you have non-numeric columns in your data.frame, you might want this:

```
remove_errors <- function(df) {
    numcols <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
    df[ , numcols] <- lapply(df[,numcols], function(x) ifelse(abs(x) > 50, NA, x))
    return(df)
}
```

Here's a test

```
set.seed(1234)
mydf <- data.frame(
    a = sample(-100:100, 20, T),
    b = sample(30:70, 20, T),
    c = sample(letters, 20, T),
    stringsAsFactors = F
)

remove_errors(mydf)
```